# custom shortcuts for launching programs in Mac

Tags: windows, macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

All,

I've been a power" windows user since 20+ years and now I'll be using a Mac (Mavericks). I look forward to some of the innovations in the Mac and at the same time dread some things that I can't do.

How to do the same in the Mac

1) In windows, if I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to a Mac program. I just need to create a shortcut for it in explorer and open the properties for the shortcut and assign the custom keyboard shortcut. What is the equivalent in Mac ?

2) In windows, I can be in command prompt in a given directory. If I want to open the explorer window in the same(current) directory, I can type "start ." and an explorer window opens displaying the contents of the current directory. How do I do that in Mac ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are a LOT of shortcut launchers for the Mac.  I used to use Keyboard Maestro for years.  It's a fine program with lots of advanced features, but it wasn't free (and it wasn't cheap, IMO).  I switched to Quicksilver, which is less-elegant to configure than Keyboard Mestro, but can open more kinds of items, like files, bookmarks, and even start a web search before you open a browser.  Quicksilver is VERY similar to Launchy and FARR for Windows.
2. I'm not on my Mac right now, but I'm fairly certain that you type `open .`.  You can use `open` to open lots of things, and in this case you're telling it to open the current directory, so the Mac passed that open request to the Finder.  BTW, there are some AppleScripts and other utilities that will open the Terminal and `cd` to the directory matches the frontmost Finder window.  You can add these to the Finder's toolbar, and then you have a 1-click method to open Terminal to the current folder.  This is equivalent to the Windows 7 feature where you have to shift-right-click in the empty (white) space in a folder, and choose "Open command window here".  Or, if you're really a Windows poweruser, you just install StExBar and get the 1-click DOS launcher (and much more!) in your StExBar.

Enjoy!

Comment: thank you. I've selected your post as answer. BTW, do you know the equivalents to the sysinternals tools like process explorer, filemon, etc ?

Comment: The Mac equiavalent of ProcExplorer is Activity Monitor.  It doesn't show the hierarchy like ProcExplorer, but it's pretty good (better than the basic Windows Task Manager anyway).  I've never used FileMon, and seems like it's been replaced anyway?  What functionality do you want?